# My Node server is keep restarting due to overflow

Tags: node.js, mongodb, server, mongodb-atlas, node-deasync

I have installed
    **`npm forever`**
plugin to restart the server.
But somehow its keep restarting every hour with following error:

```
FATAL ERROR: v8::ToLocalChecked Empty MaybeLocal.
 1: node::Abort() [node]
 2: 0x121a2cc [node]
 3: v8::Utils::ReportApiFailure(char const*, char const*) [node]
 4: node::TLSWrap::EncOut() [node]
 5: node::TLSWrap::OnReadImpl(long, uv_buf_t const*, uv_handle_type, void*) [node]
 6: node::LibuvStreamWrap::OnRead(uv_stream_s*, long, uv_buf_t const*) [node]
 7: 0x1449cbf [node]
 8: 0x144a320 [node]
 9: 0x144ffa8 [node]
10: uv_run [node]
11: Run(Nan::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> const&) [/home/ubuntu/Appname/Backend/node_modules/deasync/bin/linux-x64-node-8/deasync.node]
12: 0x7f790abe11d7 [/home/ubuntu/Appname/Backend/node_modules/deasync/bin/linux-x64-node-8/deasync.node]
13: 0x389e93f089a7
error: Forever detected script was killed by signal: SIGABRT
error: Script restart attempt #6
```

Comment: "error: Forever detected script was killed by signal: SIGABRT"

Looks like something is forcefully terminating your server, perhaps a load balancer or so, how is your server deployed?

Comment: On a side note, I recommend using `pm2` instead of `forever` it has monitoring built-in and way easier to use

Comment: I guess this is a `null` pointer exception, one of your dependency libraries is failing, please check your `package.json`. from your log I guess `deasync` library is failing.